# How to get the most frequently appearing pixel in a bmp

Tags: c, colors, rgb, pixel, bmp

As a function to determine "the base color of an image" I'm trying to implement the following code:

```
typedef unsigned long dword;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE R;
    BYTE G;
    BYTE B;
} RGB;

RGB
bitfox_get_primecolor_direct
(char *FILE_NAME)
{
    RGB primecolor;
    BYTE rgb[3];

    dword *counts;
    dword max_count = 0;

    FILE* fp = fopen("sample.bmp", "rb");

    counts = calloc(pow(256, 3), sizeof(*counts));
    fseek(fp, 54, SEEK_SET);

    while (fread (rgb, sizeof(BYTE), 3, fp) == 1)
    {
        dword idx = (((dword)rgb[0]) << 16) | (((dword)rgb[1]) << 8) | (dword)rgb[2];
        if (++counts[idx] > max_count) max_count = idx;
    }

    primecolor.R = (rgb[max_count] >> 16) & 0xFF;
    primecolor.G = (rgb[max_count] >> 8) & 0xFF;
    primecolor.B = rgb[max_count] & 0xFF;

    free(counts);
    fclose(fp);
    return primecolor;
}
```

It is supposed to be a fast algorithm ( not really thrifty when it comes to RAM ) to return RGB struct, with the base color of an image. However.. it returns the incorrect color. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I stopped at first lines but at least: sizeof(*counts)? Sure? Are you deferencing an uninitialized local variable?

Comment: You are not checking return values of `fopen` and `calloc`. Maybe those do not succeed.

Comment: @user694733 they succeeded.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Operand of `sizeof` is only evaluated if it's VLA. Otherwise it will result in integer constant (N1570: 6.5.3.4p2).

Comment: A couple of things. 1) Are you sure it is a 24 bit bmp? Alot of bitmaps are 32 bits so that they are processor aligned. 2) Are you sure it is RGB and not the more common BGR?

Comment: `fread()` returns the number of elements successfully read. Since you read 3 elements, you should do `while( fread(..) == 3)`

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Yes, im sure the bitmap is 24 bit. Paint doesn't support x32 bitmaps. (the sample image is created by paint).
Also.. even if it BGR.. it still won't return the correct value. But it is correct. Because from entirelly blue image it returns blue.

Comment: @Steffen. It should be `while(fread(..) == 1)`
The difference is that instead of indicating that you're reading three BYTEs, this says that you're reading one rgb which is really what you Im doing. It also means that if the definition of rgb ever changes, you'll only have to change it once and this code will automatically get the right size for rgb.

Comment: Also.. if i change it to `while(fread(..) == 3` this will cause u/b.
Error in invalid memory area..

Comment: @Lively. Then you should use `fread(rgb, sizeof(rgb),1,fp)`.

Comment: Well, when you use ==1 in your code, the while loop will never be executed. The fact that you do not have an invalid memory exception doesn't mean anything is correct...

Comment: Please also consider the bmp format. This starts with an header. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format. Sorry, missed that line.

Comment: @Steffen I know enough for BMPs you can be sure of it. Thats why i used fseek to move to 54 which is the offset of the pix array and where the pixels start from.

Comment: @Steffen changing it to `while(fread(..) == 3` logically does the same result. Besides the point.. the result is still incorrect. You can test it.

Comment: That image's base color is clearly magenta.. however it rerturns `R0 G0 B255` http://vegasoft.site90.com/pc_test.bmp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out already, there are several issues, the most important one the indexing of `max_count`. You can make `max_count` an index and then derive the colour from that index with the reverse logic that you used when constructing the index. This is how Steffen's and user694733's answers work.

You could also keep `max_count` as a count and assign `primecolor` when a new max count is found. That saves you the backward calculation.

Thee's a potential other issue to do with padding. The BMP format stores its data line-wise, but the number of bytes in each line must be a multiple of 4. In your case, the image is 262 pixels wide. Each line is 786 bytes long, so it must be padded to 788. If you want to take padding into account, you must know the width of the image.

Another source of confusion is that you pass a parameter `FILE_NAME` to your function, but always open `"sample.bmp"`, so you might not really get what you want.

Also, but this is a niggle, I think that the integer cube `pow(256, 3)` is better rendered as `256 * 256 * 256`.

Here's  varaint that works for me (it needs more error checking):

```
RGB bitfox_get_primecolor_direct(char *FILE_NAME)
{
    RGB primecolor = {0, 0, 0};
    BYTE hdr[54];

    dword *counts;
    dword max_count = 0;

    word w, h;
    word i, j;

    FILE* fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "rb");

    counts = calloc(256 * 256 * 256, sizeof(*counts));

    // Read header to get width and height
    fread(hdr, sizeof(hdr), 1, fp);        
    w = (hdr[19] << 8) | hdr[18];
    h = (hdr[23] << 8) | hdr[22];

    // Loop over pixels
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            RGB rgb;
            dword idx;

            if (fread(&rgb, 3, 1, fp) < 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected end of file.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            idx = (rgb.R << 16) | (rgb.G << 8) | rgb.B;
            if (++counts[idx] > max_count) {
                max_count = counts[idx];
                primecolor = rgb;
            }
        }

        // Treat padding
        j = 3 * w;
        while (j++ % 4) getc(fp);
    }

    free(counts);
    fclose(fp);

    return primecolor;
}
```

Comment: That'd be much slower though.

Comment: @Lively: You mean overwriting the colour? Yes, maybe, but I don't think it's "much" slower.

Comment: Depends. It could be just a little bid slow.. but is then multiplied by the fps restrictions i have. The program Im coding appears to be quite powerful. Everything a bit slow.. becomes much slower.

Comment: Well, implement both variants and measure. I'd wager that you wouldn't notice a big difference. I guess your focus should be on a correct answer first, anyway.

Comment: What if both answers are correct, just the one logically faster, closer to what i had and requiring less resources?

Comment: I don't really see where this discussion is going, but pick whatever suits your requirements best.

Comment: I don't know yet, Im trying them now. But since i don't think in mine algorithm padding is considered.. i don't know how to expect 100% exact results no matter image's dimensions..

Comment: i will try your variation now. It is the only one i rely of suddenly. Are you sure `while (j++ % 4) getc(fp);` isn't with `fgetc` instead?

Comment: I did like that. And it works. I'll be perfect if i knew how to reverse the values. But i'll figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: `getc` behaves the same as `fgetc`, except that it may be implemented as a macro. It's maybe better to use `fgetc`. Which values do you want to reverse? The RGB values?

Comment: Yes. I'm just using really old C and its not a console application so i can use `fgetc` instead. Yes. Instead of BGR to be RGB. I just used the same struct but BGR.. but it could be better if these were reversed from the function to fit the RGB struct.

Comment: If you don't want to swap the struct, you can swap the R and B values before returning. (But then, you could as well use Steffen's approach and store the index of the most frequent colour, then fix the RGB order when calculating the components from the index.)

Answer (score 2):

Alright. Several points:
One is the `pow` function. I found this not to behave a expected. At least on my implementation.

```
counts = calloc((dword)pow(256.0, 3.0), sizeof(dword));
```

works for me.

fread should check for the number of elements:

```
fread (rgb, sizeof(BYTE), 3, fp) == 3
```

The checking which value is max should probably be:

```
if (++(counts[idx]) > counts[max_count]) {
    max_count = idx;
}
```

And finally the extraction of the color can be done by:

```
primecolor.R = max_count >> 16 & 0xFF;
primecolor.G = max_count >> 8 & 0xFF;
primecolor.B = max_count & 0xFF;
```

With this changes it works for me. The only thing is that I get BGR. But this may result from a different image...

Complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef unsigned long dword;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE R;
    BYTE G;
    BYTE B;
} RGB;

void main (void)
{
    RGB primecolor;
    BYTE rgb[3];
    dword *counts;
    dword max_count = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen("c:/tmp/test.bmp", "rb");
    counts = calloc((dword)pow(256.0, 3.0), sizeof(dword));
    fseek(fp, 54, SEEK_SET);
    while (fread (rgb, sizeof(BYTE), 3, fp) == 3)
    {
        BYTE r = rgb[0];
        BYTE g = rgb[1];
        BYTE b = rgb[2];
        dword idx = (((dword)rgb[0]) << 16) | (((dword)rgb[1]) << 8) | (dword)rgb[2];
        if (++(counts[idx]) > counts[max_count]) {
            max_count = idx;
        }
    }
    primecolor.R = max_count >> 16 & 0xFF;
    primecolor.G = max_count >> 8 & 0xFF;
    primecolor.B = max_count & 0xFF;
    free(counts);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d %d %d ",primecolor.R,primecolor.G,primecolor.B);
}
```

This prints out 229 20 35 for an image create with gimp filled with color (RGB): 35,20,229.

Comment: Thats what i thought too.. but a friend said that it should be rgb[max_count] assuming max_count is index. Though i think it is pretty much what its name identifier says. Thanks, let me try.

Comment: hmm.. now for the same image it returns `R255 G255 B255`

Comment: I'd go for `calloc(256*256*256, sizeof(dword));`.

Comment: With all the things suggested it returns `R255 G255 B255` on http://vegasoft.site90.com/pc_test.bmp

Comment: @Steffen, if it works for you, let me try the code from above 1:1

Comment: @Steffen well it returns `R0 G0 B0` on the image unfortunately. But as Mohem stated, padding is certainly not considered. Thats most likely the reason

Comment: Simplest approach: Divide file size by imge size. Check if the result is closer to 3 or four...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to issues mentioned in comments (not checking return values, invalid `fread` return value check, possibly assuming incorrect file format...), there is an issue with `max_count`:

```
if (++counts[idx] > max_count) max_count = idx;
```

In condition you assume that `max_count` is a counter. However, in assigment you treat `max_count` as index value (which is equivalent of color). Which one it's supposed to be?

`rgb[max_count]` at the end of program makes no sense either. Again you are treating `max_count` as index (again color). `rgb` is supposed to be latest read color, thus it shouldn't be used used at all.